# dtype is string - nevertheless apply complains about not getting string-data

Tags: pandas, numpy

I encountered a seemingly weird problem when using apply on a DataFrame with a vectorized python function (via np.frompyfunc): In essence, when I declare the datatype as "string" the function complains (see below) about the datatype not being string, whereas when I use dtype=object everything is fine. Maybe someone could help me in understanding the cause of this problem.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"x": ["Car","Bike"]},dtype='string')

#some method to apply to the x-column
def split(x):
    print(x)
    return x.split("O")

# vectorized version -> needed for apply method
split_v = np.frompyfunc(split,1,1)

# in a simple for-loop everything is fine
for i in range(len(df)):
    split(df["x"][i])

# Error: "StringArray requires a sequence of strings or pandas.NA"
df2 = df[["x"]].apply(split_v,axis=1, result_type="expand")

# Simply defining dtype as object does not cause the error: 
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": ["Car","Bike"]})
df2 = df[["x"]].apply(split_v,axis=1, result_type="expand")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should show the full traceback.  But having run your code I think it comes down to problem running the `frompyfunc` function on this special pandas dtype.  Normally pandas uses object dtype and ordinary python strings.

Here's how `split_v` operates on an ordinary list of strings:

```
In [89]: split_v(['astring', 'aOb'])
astring
aOb
Out[89]: array([list(['astring']), list(['a', 'b'])], dtype=object)
```

Note the result is object dtype, containing lists.

Your dataframe column:

```
In [90]: df['x']
Out[90]: 
0     Car
1    Bike
Name: x, dtype: string
```

and the array form:

```
In [91]: df['x'].values
Out[91]: 
<StringArray>
['Car', 'Bike']
Length: 2, dtype: string
```

applying `split_v` to that raises your error:

```
In [92]: split_v(df['x'].values)
Car
Bike
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[92], line 1
    split_v(df['x'].values)

  File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\numpy_.py:188 in __array_ufunc__
    return type(self)(result)

  File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\string_.py:319 in __init__
    self._validate()

  File ~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\string_.py:325 in _validate
    raise ValueError("StringArray requires a sequence of strings or pandas.NA")

ValueError: StringArray requires a sequence of strings or pandas.NA
```

If instead I convert the argument to object dtype:

```
In [93]: df['x'].values.astype(object)
Out[93]: array(['Car', 'Bike'], dtype=object)

In [94]: split_v(df['x'].values.astype(object))
Car
Bike
Out[94]: array([list(['Car']), list(['Bike'])], dtype=object)
```

I don't know much about this `pandas` `StringArray` dtype, but it's clearly adding a layer of processing on top of the strings, both for pandas and the underlying numpy.

This pandas 'string' dtype is not an ordinary pandas string, nor a numpy 'Un' type of string.  It's a special pandas construct.

```
In [111]: df['x']
Out[111]: 
0     Car
1    Bike
Name: x, dtype: string

In [112]: df['x'].dtype
Out[112]: string[python]

In [113]: type(df['x'].dtype)
Out[113]: pandas.core.arrays.string_.StringDtype
```

### edit

While scanning the pandas docs on text, https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html

I wonder if you need this `split_v` and `apply`.  Just do

```
In [114]: df['x'].str.split('O')
Out[114]: 
0     [Car]
1    [Bike]
Name: x, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - you are correct. I also traced the various functions which are applied in sequence and it seems that the problem is that the special pandas Stringdtype does some additional validation if the data conform to string. However it does not apply any conversions. Hence, as you said, the dtype when returning from the np.frompyfunc is object and although it is convertible to string, the validate function spits out an error. In any case, I find the usage of this special string-dtype more confusing than helpful.